# TSQL: how to delete last record from query result if record is NULL

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, null

**Background:**
I am using a stored procedure below to retrieve hourly time series data.

```
SELECT *
   FROM (
      SELECT CAST(LocalDateTime as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], DataValue, VariableID
         FROM DataValues
         WHERE SiteID = 2 and VariableID IN(1,3,30)
         ) TableDate
   PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([1],[3],[30]))
   PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

Usually the data is written to the database at the top of the hour, and the stored procedure is executed at 5 minutes past the hour to retrieve all existing values.

The problem is that occasionally the data retrieval on top of the hour fails for one of many sites and thus no new data is written to the `DataValues` table for that site.  However, the most recent hour is still present in the `DataValues` table because other sites wrote values to it.  This results in a query result that has a record for the most recent hour but all fields are `NULL`.  The code that handles the query results can deal with hourly data that is `NULL` for whatever reason except in cases where the very last record is `NULL` for all fields.

**Question:**
Is there a simple way to remove the last record of a query result (once pivoted per procedure above) if all fields of that record are `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with by using `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
      SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalDateTime as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], DataValue, VariableID
            FROM DataValues
            WHERE SiteID = 2 and VariableID IN(1,3,30)
           ) TableDate
      PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([1],[3],[30])) PivotTable
      ORDER BY [DateTime]
     )
select [DateTime], [1], [3], [30]
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (order by [DateTime] desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and [1] is null and [3] is null and [30] is null;
```

However, I think the easiest way is just to filter before the `pivot`:

```
      SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT CAST(LocalDateTime as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], DataValue, VariableID
            FROM DataValues
            WHERE DataValue is not null
            WHERE SiteID = 2 and VariableID IN (1, 3, 30)
           ) TableDate
      PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([1],[3],[30])) PivotTable
      ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

This has the potential disadvantage of removing other rows with `NULL`s in them.  If that is a problem, the first method works better.